# Issue when launching url from command line in IE8

Tags: command-line, internet-explorer-8, url

If I paste the following url directly into the address bar of internet explorer

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?layer=c&cbll=56.18231,10.20435&cbp=12,70
```

the related google maps streetview is shown.

If instead I try

```
start "" "http://maps.google.com/maps?layer=c&cbll=56.18231,10.20435&cbp=12,70"
```

this url is shown and no streetview

```
https://www.google.com/maps/@/data=!3m3!1e1!3m1!2e0
```

The problem only occurs when IE is the default browser. With Chrome as default browser the streetview is displayed correctly also when using the start command at command prompt.

Any idea what could be going wrong? I have also tried

```
rundll32.exe url.dll,FileProtocolHandler http://maps.google.com/maps?layer=c&cbll=56.18231,10.20435&cbp=12,70
```

to no avail.

The customer that I am setting this up for is using IE 8. There are no issues with higher IE versions, or Chrome

Comment: can you be more specific than `start "" ""`  it'd be a bit strange if `start "" ""` even launched a web browser let alone a location in google maps

Comment: The line, which supposedly starts the default browser, was:

`start "" "http://maps.google.com/maps?layer=c&cbll=56.18231,10.20435&cbp=12,70"`

Comment: I should add: this customer that I am setting this up for is using IE 8. There are no issues with higher IE versions, or Chrome.

Comment: Question fixed as per OP's comments.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
start "" "http://maps.google.com/maps?layer=c&cbll=56.18231,10.20435&cbp=12,70"
```

this will start the file http://maps.google.com/maps?layer=c&cbll=56.18231,10.20435&cbp=12,70 which is a website so it will open it with internet explorer the first set of brackets is the program you want to open it with but as internet explorer is the default the first set can be left blank

Comment: That is exactly what was in the question (which wasn't formatted very well - so you couldn't see the URL). I've fixed the question.

Comment: Thanks to both, my initial question was indeed poorly formatted. @AlexanderRD: your solution works if the default browser is not IE8. But I need a solution for IE8.